# Allowing IKEv2 on Windows Firewall

Tags: networking, vpn, firewall

I am using a VPN service from a company that offers IKEv2 VPN. I tried enabling it in the Windows Firewall by allowing UDP ports 500 and 4500. I also allowed Protocol number 50 and 51 without luck. I am able to connect to the service but "No network access." In other words, no internet access. When I fully disable the Windows Firewall, I have internet access. How do I allow IKEv2 VPN traffic through. By the way, when I looked at the logs I noticed how Protocol 4 (IPv4) packets are dropped. How can I enable IKEv2 without enabling the entire IPv4 packets. The only workaround I know is adding the blocked IP from dropped protocol 4 packets into a protocol 4 rule. Though, I want to have something generic. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> When I fully disable the Windows Firewall, I have internet access.

It's weird. By default, the Windows firewall will not block any outbound traffic.
[image: Firewall outbound]

When we connect a VPN server, we will forward all of the traffic to the VPN server. And the VPN server should forward these packets to the internet correctly. If the VPN server doesn't help on forwarding the internet traffic, you will encounter this issue.

You have two options to resolve it：

1. Make sure that the VPN server has suitable route to forward the packets from VPN clients to the internet.
2. Remove the default gateway pointed to the VPN server and add some suitable static routes to access the subnets behind the VPN server.
   [image: VPN Gateway]

Comment: Yes, I changed my firewall to deny all with exceptions. I add everything manually to allow everything I need. What is interesting is my firewall has the rules to allow every type of VPN with the exception of IKE and they work without issues. I have tried several IKEv2 VPN providers and I am faced with the same issue.

Comment: If you change it back to the default (Allow outbound traffic), does your client get the internet? If yes, please change it back. It's not necessary to block all outbound traffic. It may cause a lot of unexpected error if you don't know every outbound connection needed by the system. The outbound traffic restriction is normally performed on the border firewall.

Comment: I do not want to fully allow outbound traffic, though. I just want to allow IKEv2. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

IKE across a NAT router requires using the NAT traversal option (NAT-T). NAT-T uses full UDP encapsulation to the server destination port 4500.

Port 500 for native IKE and protocols 50 (ESP) & 51 (AH) are useless here as they break with NAT.